# send pdf to server and save it in database

Tags: php, android, pdf, server, multipartentity

I try to send pdf and text from android app to server , I succeeded in sending text. the problem is i can't send pdf , I don't if the problem in android code or php code so could anyone help me in this problem
 android code

```
 private class postData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    EditText email = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.email);
    EditText phone = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.email);
    String eemail=email.getText().toString();
    String pphone=phone.getText().toString();
    EditText first  = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.firstname);
    EditText second= (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.lastname);
    String firstname=first.getText().toString();
    String lastname=second.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://phone.tmsline.com/api/request_job");
        String json = "";
        String responseStr="";
        String result="true";


        try {
            // Add your data

            File uploadFile1 = new File("/sdcard/Download/Testing foundation.pdf");

          FileBody fileBody = new FileBody( uploadFile1 , ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY);
            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();


            builder.addPart("cv",new FileBody(uploadFile1));
            builder.addPart("email", new StringBody(eemail));
            builder.addPart("phone", new StringBody(pphone));
            builder.addPart("firstname", new StringBody(firstname));
            builder.addPart("lastname", new StringBody(lastname));
            HttpEntity entity = builder.build();


            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            try {
                httpclient.execute(httppost);
               // filetest();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }


            // Execute HTTP Post Request

           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

           responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());




        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("HTTP Failed", e.toString());

        }
        return responseStr;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String responseStr) {
        super.onPostExecute(responseStr);

        String result="";
        String  test="";
        String msg="msg";
        int x=1;

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),responseStr,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            JSONArray pp=new JSONArray(responseStr);
            result = pp.getString(x)     Toast.makeText(getActivity(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();






            //result is key for which you need to retrieve data
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }



    }
```

**php code**

```
public function add_resume(Request $request){
    $resume = new Resume;
    $resume->first_name = $request->firstname;
    $resume->last_name = $request->lastname;
    $resume->phone = $request->phone;
    $resume->email = $request->email;
    $file = $request->file('cv');
    $ext = $file->guessExtension();
    $ext=".".$ext;
    $filename=md5(time().mt_rand());
    $file->move(storage_path('app/public/uploads'),$filename.$ext);
    $resume->cv = $filename.$ext;
    $resume->save();
    return response()->json(['cv','1']);
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final MyAttachmentViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        attachments=alist.get(position);
        holder.filename.setText(attachments.get(FragmentAssignmentDetails.FILE));
        holder.viewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onClick(View v) {
                                                     boolean internet = new Internetcheck(contex).isOnline();
                                                     if (internet) {
                                                         attachments=alist.get(position);
                                                         String filename = attachments.get(FragmentAssignmentDetails.FILE);
                                                         Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                                         filename.toLowerCase();
                                                         if (filename.endsWith("jpeg") || filename.endsWith("jpg") || filename.endsWith("png") || filename.endsWith("JPG") || filename.endsWith("PNG") || filename.endsWith("JPEG")) {
                                                             bundle.putString("filetype", "imagefile");

                                                         } else if (filename.endsWith("flv") || filename.endsWith("mp4") || filename.endsWith("mov")) {
                                                             bundle.putString("filetype", "videofile");
                                                         } else {
                                                             bundle.putString("filetype", "noimage");
                                                         }
                                                         Fragment fragment = new FragmentWebview();
                                                         bundle.putString("link", (url+filename));
                                                         fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                                                         android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = ((android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity) contex).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                                         fragmentTransaction.setTransition(android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                                                         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
                                                         fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                                                         fragmentTransaction.commit();

                                                     } else {
                                                         Toast.makeText(contex, "No internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                     }
                                                 }
                                             }
        );
        holder.downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                attachments=alist.get(position);
                filename = attachments.get(FragmentAssignmentDetails.FILE);
                String filelink = url+filename;
                sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + contex.getString(R.string.sdirname) + "/" + foldername + "/" + filename);
                String str = directory.getAbsolutePath().toString();
                if (directory.exists()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    if (str.endsWith("pdf") || str.endsWith("PDF")) {
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(directory), "application/pdf");
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                        contex.startActivity(intent);
                    } else if (str.endsWith("docx") || str.endsWith("doc")) {
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(directory), "application/msword");
                        contex.startActivity(intent);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                    } else if (str.endsWith("jpeg") || str.endsWith("jpg") || str.endsWith("png") || str.endsWith("JPG") || str.endsWith("PNG") || str.endsWith("JPEG")) {
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(directory), "image/*");
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                        contex.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(contex, "App not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    internet = new Internetcheck(contex).isOnline();
                    if (internet) {
                        task = (DownloadFileFromURL) new DownloadFileFromURL(contex).execute(filelink);
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(contex, "No internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }


            }
        });
    }
```